# How to plot spatial data when grid cell size varies

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, geom-raster

I am trying to make a map of global model predictions with the outline of the world on it.

The data I have cover most of the worlds oceans and the grid cells have a resolution of 4 degrees. This is my desired output: [Map of global predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNXfr.png)

This is the code I have tried using:

```
# Packages
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(ggspatial)

# Subset of data (500 rows, 4 columns; Longitude, Latitude, Prediction, Grid cell area)

data <- structure(list(Longitude = c(-10.16956752, 126.1689468, -61.99876686, 
-94.00000289, 126.0007703, 170.000033, 82.55726146, -6.495772811, 
-149.9999879, -61.99897757, -89.99998854, 2.000011459, 122.1211726, 
-2.593090202, -17.99998854, -170.0001433, 121.8262874, 10.21256204, 
166.0000115, 158.3111356, 134.3679695, -13.73648415, 170.0000423, 
92.91243971, 5.996191823, 62.00001146, -53.99998854, -21.99998854, 
125.9910976, 154.0000115, 149.9995576, -77.88731531, -45.99998854, 
-33.99998854, -5.878402842, -157.9999885, -169.9929349, 66.00001146, 
-138.5853402, -17.99998854, -69.99998854, -56.79830902, 110.0502773, 
50.00001146, 39.56890984, -146.0004371, -5.999521688, 18.72192101, 
-69.77517581, 21.3289268, 42.00001146, 162.0000115, 165.9995769, 
-162.0365539, 170.0000138, 142.0000446, -45.99998854, -165.9999885, 
110.0000115, -25.99998854, 6.000011459, -89.99998854, -53.99998854, 
50.00187439, 146.0000115, -134.3123896, 165.9543502, -169.9999885, 
-81.89972865, 72.42284406, 134.0000115, -170.0197871, -96.6556298, 
17.92812, -152.9139565, -9.999988541, -73.99998854, 158.0000115, 
54.20603343, 157.9995854, 74.00034763, -157.9999902, 102.4769658, 
-73.99191424, 6.000011459, 162.0000177, -10.07971318, -93.99998854, 
90.00001146, 153.9999475, 162.0000115, 117.9915582, -33.99998854, 
38.00001146, -77.99998854, -81.99998854, 74.00022314, 114.1420482, 
-173.9974719, 118.4796001, 178.0206217, 42.00001146, 178, -138.000174, 
146.6226982, 165.999998, -49.73916727, -37.99998854, 137.9999465, 
38.00001146, -82.04904949, 119.0280587, -169.9999946, 162.855343, 
113.9999563, -61.9672714, 50.12191729, -173.9999885, 41.85382837, 
130.0000115, 126.5154259, -37.93913378, 62.00001146, 129.9747567, 
-161.9999885, -137.9999787, -1.958606869, 165.9999802, 150.1568838, 
13.72012633, -37.59668977, 162.0000061, -29.99998854, -177.9999885, 
117.9999058, -149.9999885, 114.0000063, 96.91839389, -29.99998854, 
-25.99998854, -93.99998854, -29.99998854, 170.0000115, -173.9999885, 
142.0105738, -37.9593374, 9.937003613, 145.9958965, -178.0133745, 
-78.74777464, -122.0023764, -178.0000115, 162.0000115, -169.9999885, 
-141.9999885, 158.0000115, -85.99998854, -15.44057437, 30.01655738, 
-161.9999885, 35.50200234, 173.9999943, 5.999766664, 58.00001146, 
-14.27262379, 53.59629681, 146.0999455, 53.97807051, 178.3714871, 
174.0000115, -173.9999885, 46.05658123, 154.0000115, -150.0013408, 
130.3202993, 5.888053059, 70.00001146, -137.9971843, -57.99998854, 
-153.9999885, 38.51576452, 5.356846647, -177.9999885, 38.21244542, 
22.06404301, -85.99990114, 165.9999621, 42.06833294, 82.38551366, 
-69.26776454, -149.9999885, 105.7885139, -162.0000326, 17.01965058, 
-74.66124649, -61.84333457, 154.0000125, 170.0162654, 1.824314695, 
13.82919973, -166.2490329, 2.000011459, 58.00381545, 162.269909, 
70.00001146, 126.2275842, -85.99069255, -161.9999885, -145.9998563, 
-110.8963681, -45.6718642, 106.1072479, 150.0124763, 173.9999974, 
129.7397288, -53.99998854, -174.0231047, 142.4679548, 6.084793515, 
165.951299, 174.0000115, 58.00001146, 54.00001146, -78.41571925, 
22.04138072, -87.07057574, -105.9999885, -109.9999885, -37.99998854, 
9.440334846, -74.33053694, -65.97004746, -49.99998854, -73.95814747, 
-74.74355347, 117.7688064, 78.00001146, 170.0004612, -126.0474866, 
-10.14156626, 41.44639846, -65.99998854, 150.0007478, 138.1284291, 
166.0000115, -177.9999885, 165.9998751, 122.5803857, -1.832865108, 
-78.22084003, 145.9777733, 154.0040729, -57.99998854, -73.99998854, 
-17.99998854, 97.66893601, -73.99998854, 58.00448, 158.0000123, 
-161.9999831, 10.00001146, -70.11943583, 90.00001146, -93.90742733, 
122.0381743, 90.02820747, 114.0000115, 178.0002266, 94.03546334, 
-13.99998854, 2.026556417, 170.0816676, 170.0000105, 174.0000115, 
-177.9999885, -157.9999885, 134.0000243, -74.01378632, 14.07846074, 
4.926681381, 166.0000115, -178.0000102, -18.22132114, -41.76260639, 
-165.9999885, -173.9999848, 117.8546849, 13.97253564, 138.0000115, 
2.000011459, -57.86039422, -162.000012, -169.9967526, -60.85299577, 
-37.53072648, -81.99781314, 138.0875793, 169.8994304, 107.4007518, 
-73.99998854, 53.99801704, 46.00001146, 25.98144338, 66.00001146, 
114.0000316, 110.0000115, 112.9024546, 177.9564699, -1.999988541, 
-82.00000426, 162.0082822, -69.24184951, 101.9020192, -173.9995473, 
-49.27150176, 21.92369036, 138.4587056, -66.29757086, -26.0078251, 
174.0000131, 133.9889887, 38.16885146, -5.999988541, 133.9391315, 
-61.99998854, 8.706431568, -49.8624759, 130.0106889, -13.99998854, 
-177.9999885, -1.969664455, 113.1977475, 94.00376755, 82.00293912, 
-61.49274336, 78.05701813, 109.8622452, 151.2237393, 154.0000115, 
166.0000115, 13.64867252, -90.74983985, -54.5837941, 150.0593517, 
-30.00737278, 10.14403385, 165.9999579, 141.99997, -71.49830857, 
-57.99636593, 126.0072243, -21.94802182, -109.8907217, -9.999988541, 
-61.96780638, -137.9996316, 106.0499776, 158.0000115, -65.08399512, 
178, 65.83642764, 125.9426387, -157.9992733, 50.00001146, 38.06053256, 
69.99999724, 129.6863334, -166.3675674, -11.16300072, 53.62409287, 
137.7173457, 126.0031256, 118.9525785, 154.0010114, -162.0000077, 
34.00001146, -5.999988541, -94.32614301, 25.43306958, 142.2242709, 
37.21917664, 138.0000115, -49.99998854, -109.999023, 173.6014161, 
40.58655549, 14.30990335, -65.58554854, -153.9096668, 121.8307417, 
174.0000115, -74.05492837, -17.99998854, -96.82143996, 10.00001146, 
165.989779, 54.00001146, 9.648264537, -153.9996769, -1.379131047, 
-33.99967232, -13.99998854, -13.99998863, -29.99998854, -157.9993798, 
130.3986089, -149.9540973, -66.05141375, -117.9995487, -69.99998854, 
-10.08258389, 113.9349012, 50.88704952, -48.62667494, -49.99998854, 
-114.0201716, -133.999895, -102.1160738, -174.0044266, 145.728285, 
-21.99998854, 138.0034532, -93.99998854, 125.1209634, 133.9987429, 
-141.9999885, 133.94514, -75.16942252, 13.30257806, -57.91461701, 
58.00001146, 169.9995982, 38.92821472, 70.00001146, 12.76082336, 
-77.99998854, -78.00228912, -81.799125, 130.0491847, 46.00091358, 
154.117492, -82.0003813, 102.1876905, 50.11824049, 6.000011459, 
-41.75455025, -57.99998854, -18.15791357, -53.94267298, -33.99998854, 
146.0000115, 142.0000115, 58.78666498, -45.99998854, 174.0000115, 
-153.999987, 102.0000115, 125.9624191, 157.9999468, 170.027281, 
154.0000115, -57.99998854, -177.994726, 46.00001146, 153.9999931, 
-9.999988541, -165.9999925, -89.9340042, -86.0160541, -25.8730291, 
58.00001146, 118.0000115, -122.5807138, 46.00001146, 110.0000115, 
121.829682, 46.59514055, -157.9999885, -153.9999885, 62.00001146, 
-169.9997623, 126.103807, -10.52623514, 173.8637862, 130.0192184, 
-18.02951352, -10.00000412, 121.9939471, 154.2592125, -69.35640587, 
142.6960182, -153.9999943, -57.89841693, 70.00001146, 101.5055217, 
170.0000115, 14.00001146, -86.04945349, 113.4322028, -158.0211136
), Latitude = c(3.820825091, 12.08126747, -55.97816596, 0.022599112, 
16.02343874, 0.022652324, 8.210545822, 35.69956109, -7.977383247, 
20.02440074, -3.977389136, 68.02261086, 0.21132112, 48.20584876, 
56.02261086, -19.97848897, -15.77200491, 39.96397297, -55.97738914, 
51.31485551, 42.7205338, 63.73313502, -11.97738132, 19.14158715, 
0.020484685, -11.97738914, 56.02261086, 12.02261086, 28.03092594, 
-15.97738914, 8.022784025, 31.90009355, 4.022610864, -19.97738914, 
3.470593567, 52.02261086, -11.96980917, -19.97738914, 58.63570686, 
60.02261086, 36.02261086, -36.03332986, 19.86853597, -7.977389136, 
-5.079794602, -15.97762273, 72.02282038, 60.02451001, 20.43051724, 
56.88863607, -27.97738914, -51.97738914, -51.98251101, 56.0994785, 
12.02263258, 32.02264073, 48.02261086, -39.97738914, -23.97738914, 
12.02261086, 72.02261086, 8.022610864, -39.97738914, -23.97920822, 
52.02261086, 55.56880819, -15.99570073, 0.022610864, 16.10672797, 
19.81627886, 40.02261086, 52.00303707, 27.1872715, -36.06367709, 
59.08122925, 64.02261086, -31.97738914, 48.02261086, 15.52636519, 
-11.9775079, -7.977528124, -7.97730525, 0.334377082, 24.03404499, 
68.02261086, 8.022600292, 56.12108887, 24.02261086, 8.022610864, 
8.022581727, -23.97738914, -7.848129941, -31.97738914, 72.02261086, 
-51.97738914, -11.97738914, 4.022581755, -8.010086532, -19.9761759, 
23.37409625, -35.91559755, -31.97738914, 60.02261086, -19.97753078, 
-15.74140829, 20.02262634, 4.188582753, -27.97738914, 8.02189791, 
76.02261086, -8.031710615, 38.78875047, 16.02260157, 55.55599452, 
12.02268181, 48.082086, 28.08551543, 56.02261086, -24.05829182, 
8.022610864, 8.196719853, -20.01786497, -15.97738914, -7.986975327, 
-19.97738914, -15.97735921, 60.07070103, 8.022585242, -7.833875605, 
39.59151568, -3.200384655, 12.02261958, -7.977389136, -31.97738914, 
-11.97749469, 56.02261086, 8.022591881, 15.30078904, 4.022610864, 
60.02261086, 4.022610864, 64.02261086, -55.97738914, 0.022610864, 
56.02527798, 63.87882091, -15.94729501, -11.98168222, 63.80828291, 
4.17958317, 32.02014727, -23.97741025, -27.97738914, 60.02261086, 
-11.97738914, -15.97738914, 0.022610864, 25.12307726, 35.30667652, 
52.02261086, -20.53611794, -3.977401906, 56.02228724, 0.022610864, 
28.3079482, 25.16859735, 44.05525808, -19.96113513, -40.28569378, 
-15.97738914, -23.97738914, -0.037988625, 16.02261086, -15.96585368, 
39.81030641, 64.19614498, 12.02261086, -7.973236555, 68.02261086, 
16.02261086, 20.02052366, 53.42403026, -47.97738914, 68.94567437, 
-36.10729177, 4.022489321, 12.02268765, -4.044358874, 15.51366591, 
-52.17439793, -19.97738914, -8.252118386, 4.022523768, -32.17125459, 
-52.30061977, 68.25610808, 24.02260363, 59.26701564, 37.27072488, 
-28.09811868, 68.08853997, 64.02261086, 16.01865467, 60.12532688, 
0.022610864, -33.20386499, 16.93217855, -23.97738914, -23.97739795, 
27.03071622, -24.85901806, 0.086841557, 43.99971799, 0.022528258, 
31.83167869, 8.022610864, 63.3986452, -2.559698337, 42.73623655, 
-48.0292721, -31.97738914, -3.977389136, -27.97738914, 8.131263575, 
33.25599506, 11.25544918, 16.02261086, 16.02261086, -31.97738914, 
43.07891697, -35.77986134, 12.2126783, -35.97738914, 36.00374653, 
-39.94361536, -4.13230838, 4.022610864, 56.02295289, 40.00081489, 
44.13941424, 16.06104742, 24.02261086, 0.026048965, 43.88233783, 
-31.97738914, -35.97738914, 0.02269025, 15.93016831, 36.33475991, 
64.08957191, 58.69065802, -11.9821079, -43.97738914, -19.97738914, 
8.022610864, 7.886221494, 28.02261086, -19.97425468, 4.022609044, 
8.022632834, 76.02261086, -56.35045724, 12.02261086, 27.76247933, 
20.11429594, 19.94635242, -11.97738914, 0.022800625, 12.01506492, 
52.02261086, 3.990144293, -48.119873, -23.97739031, -47.97738914, 
-7.977389136, -15.97738914, 4.02260161, -55.9950546, 55.17829816, 
59.78172479, -39.97738914, -27.97709912, 19.91987466, 59.82242042, 
-7.977389136, 28.0226185, -19.22686648, 35.75467029, 28.02261086, 
60.02261086, 56.24693609, 0.022615635, -15.98239129, 56.91608985, 
-16.00820732, 19.99353474, -11.93590796, -43.44797102, 17.39564775, 
-27.97738914, -3.97660846, -27.97738914, 72.3771239, 20.02261086, 
16.02260062, 8.022610864, -23.92922118, -15.87608439, 0.022610864, 
4.02261266, -12.00190948, 43.02433176, 3.940700587, 52.02051602, 
0.453746804, 35.80665248, 55.46846217, 60.44655603, 64.01596898, 
-23.97739048, -8.021036568, 41.55396512, 0.022610864, -36.03540447, 
-47.97738914, 0.18180871, -32.12616329, 28.02527243, 4.022610864, 
60.02261086, 3.585780138, -28.19444665, 8.026970975, 4.01869224, 
-40.6633516, 7.641169912, -4.189248799, -22.79978441, -35.97738914, 
-35.97738914, 68.39801011, 20.72995388, 71.34060756, -39.94398235, 
40.03156039, 56.27043197, -7.977302797, 0.022696615, -27.65147886, 
12.01992286, -11.98018915, 68.03301665, 23.77432249, 60.02261086, 
-44.00407701, -11.9781651, 7.869716893, 24.02261086, -44.63876721, 
-43.97738914, 23.57520672, -0.00367899, -19.9766619, -27.97738914, 
-20.03795661, -3.977378548, -11.69278291, 63.64955575, 29.33031037, 
26.56177022, -36.35002015, 24.02124134, 3.824165017, 48.01687813, 
-11.97742276, -31.97738914, 68.02261086, 14.9567938, 39.49419331, 
52.14461318, 23.59920469, -39.97738914, 44.02261086, 20.02378979, 
-39.82478245, 18.89622815, 33.19261424, 64.03632422, 20.04775234, 
7.962805467, -11.97738914, 20.14118871, 36.02261086, 23.88593283, 
-7.977389136, -24.0052275, 0.022610864, -4.304016102, -3.977239696, 
56.33643088, 64.02229033, 36.02261086, 56.0226104, 36.02261086, 
4.02276095, 35.97473352, 59.19366534, 43.43616188, 28.02104594, 
28.02261086, 35.94314023, -19.90137354, 7.666766431, -28.51031591, 
52.02261086, 24.00874176, -23.97747135, 15.87276871, 60.02116361, 
-8.698681751, 60.02261086, 32.01724937, 12.02261086, 39.03817517, 
8.023956758, -27.97738914, 36.52433482, -47.86022133, -24.05345441, 
51.29963345, 12.02261086, 8.0230886, -17.44438098, 4.022610864, 
-11.64166378, -47.97738914, 28.04187363, 12.02387396, -32.82633622, 
-11.97100486, -23.86540067, -31.97684268, 8.220758027, 12.50957099, 
-7.977389136, -2.362973126, 64.02261086, 11.93486197, 52.02216857, 
4.022610864, 56.02261086, -43.97738914, 19.46370663, -27.97738914, 
-7.977389136, -19.97738511, -7.977389136, -4.012441622, -3.97733509, 
-15.96734551, -19.97738662, 40.02261086, -15.9747231, -31.97738914, 
4.022573507, 68.02261086, -11.97740656, 27.83155686, 27.99326446, 
67.48803929, -23.97738914, 20.02261086, 35.66604315, -3.977389136, 
-27.97738914, 11.9231427, -25.17266991, -11.97738914, -23.97738914, 
-23.97738914, -3.977488904, -7.815115494, 32.26364968, -35.8672365, 
4.044041471, 68.08721908, -39.97720998, -12.03217659, -32.12480347, 
60.72642244, 58.57913449, -15.97736476, -40.14518463, 16.02261086, 
-4.507175688, 52.02261086, -31.97738914, 7.959477669, 4.883317505, 
19.98977949), y = c(224, 277, 48, 33, 224, 14, 372, 205, 10, 
110, 24, 10, 234, 105, 14, 43, 358, 186, 5, 5, 48, 38, 33, 353, 
153, 24, 10, 10, 305, 76, 38, 167, 167, 62, 238, 10, 52, 10, 
14, 14, 10, 210, 372, 81, 205, 57, 10, 5, 110, 5, 57, 5, 19, 
14, 33, 48, 10, 5, 43, 10, 5, 5, 176, 157, 10, 33, 62, 14, 153, 
343, 29, 14, 181, 167, 14, 38, 76, 5, 262, 91, 24, 33, 381, 119, 
24, 33, 91, 134, 52, 38, 10, 348, 5, 10, 52, 10, 124, 401, 48, 
501, 62, 14, 5, 52, 296, 10, 181, 5, 29, 5, 176, 134, 24, 5, 
129, 24, 253, 5, 167, 5, 277, 162, 19, 291, 29, 52, 76, 33, 195, 
176, 176, 29, 5, 33, 205, 19, 396, 329, 5, 10, 14, 5, 5, 14, 
10, 10, 195, 319, 5, 210, 134, 43, 5, 5, 24, 5, 10, 176, 167, 
14, 238, 24, 76, 5, 200, 248, 43, 72, 62, 33, 38, 172, 10, 57, 
86, 48, 172, 38, 5, 19, 195, 62, 14, 5, 186, 38, 33, 191, 367, 
76, 19, 401, 14, 143, 62, 5, 5, 5, 181, 114, 5, 43, 234, 5, 5, 
181, 143, 10, 38, 262, 253, 396, 10, 33, 310, 186, 5, 176, 176, 
48, 52, 105, 5, 348, 167, 215, 33, 10, 5, 176, 76, 186, 277, 
162, 72, 343, 114, 5, 62, 138, 205, 5, 129, 57, 14, 5, 29, 253, 
186, 5, 5, 153, 134, 10, 238, 429, 24, 72, 38, 29, 5, 52, 52, 
186, 462, 396, 5, 33, 257, 43, 234, 48, 62, 24, 14, 14, 38, 48, 
38, 76, 14, 33, 253, 10, 10, 24, 386, 186, 5, 72, 10, 10, 52, 
10, 153, 105, 343, 52, 343, 10, 105, 157, 14, 114, 124, 367, 
377, 57, 5, 33, 100, 67, 381, 14, 181, 172, 5, 10, 29, 14, 305, 
10, 5, 176, 95, 238, 277, 267, 10, 5, 238, 324, 200, 324, 162, 
420, 377, 296, 134, 10, 33, 181, 5, 191, 33, 72, 38, 124, 76, 
124, 353, 19, 267, 81, 153, 52, 415, 10, 138, 33, 362, 224, 38, 
14, 238, 24, 358, 5, 181, 248, 191, 215, 401, 5, 33, 62, 5, 210, 
157, 19, 195, 119, 19, 105, 62, 191, 186, 5, 57, 300, 33, 129, 
5, 186, 215, 91, 10, 234, 29, 81, 10, 14, 38, 19, 29, 267, 19, 
52, 114, 5, 176, 358, 195, 272, 10, 224, 48, 195, 5, 305, 5, 
229, 124, 157, 43, 19, 257, 57, 95, 19, 5, 38, 224, 72, 200, 
29, 181, 157, 181, 167, 300, 5, 420, 267, 5, 176, 5, 253, 19, 
5, 5, 43, 253, 253, 24, 14, 86, 224, 119, 52, 277, 5, 62, 10, 
29, 10, 33, 191, 195, 19, 29, 339, 134, 5, 33, 324, 172, 10, 
19, 5, 33, 286, 186, 57, 181, 19, 5, 329, 267, 5, 5, 48, 181, 
315, 257, 10, 81, 219, 424, 57), AreaKM2 = c(172379.8637, 167621.7823, 
111118.7471, 196904.8, 189369.6807, 196896.989, 134153.5568, 
71970.27812, 195050.3834, 185116.288, 196444.6159, 74544.74404, 
135009.3945, 61775.80703, 111062.6969, 185126.4021, 164516.111, 
124340.3488, 111191.639, 68700.83531, 43856.91162, 70108.90819, 
192725.4358, 52368.79493, 195854.878, 192730.4345, 111062.6969, 
192698.9311, 173434.9048, 189491.6891, 194962.3356, 155420.9957, 
196434.0627, 185346.9753, 140635.0673, 122178.9993, 191978.3737, 
185346.9753, 23658.60183, 99380.08521, 159993.6391, 42922.78337, 
120817.5266, 195050.9669, 19360.96145, 189306.2305, 61499.9413, 
56362.06723, 133811.001, 36208.14872, 174407.0449, 122301.2318, 
121784.3494, 97667.61516, 192695.2501, 167570.6517, 132676.5593, 
151724.8938, 180312.2014, 192698.9312, 61515.16271, 195029.8994, 
151724.8937, 180138.6045, 122178.9993, 70469.59767, 182207.8668, 
196906.2159, 178430.7004, 35127.21608, 151626.0232, 120088.3123, 
34967.02013, 152173.9234, 21689.94623, 87187.46134, 167655.0629, 
132676.5593, 137692.4358, 192687.7134, 195008.928, 195034.9023, 
37709.23621, 177760.0238, 74544.74403, 195028.7223, 104452.2905, 
180250.2648, 195029.8994, 194985.5096, 180312.2015, 168803.3062, 
167655.0629, 61515.16273, 122301.2318, 192730.4345, 196367.3912, 
154833.4069, 184773.8213, 103635.3051, 154987.4071, 167655.0629, 
99379.51582, 185295.6034, 124572.0368, 185291.0797, 166948.1787, 
174407.0449, 194937.1264, 48164.88123, 189140.5621, 28961.24096, 
189447.4124, 50911.15111, 192688.7448, 114247.0282, 105516.4578, 
111062.6969, 166115.7123, 195029.8994, 117024.6708, 179379.4406, 
189491.6891, 189395.9156, 185346.9753, 189487.5792, 94441.42754, 
195024.8608, 166013.9648, 105637.9472, 106848.1233, 192695.752, 
195050.9669, 167655.0629, 192720.1173, 111062.6969, 195027.5475, 
56141.14169, 196434.0627, 99380.08521, 196434.0627, 87187.46136, 
111191.639, 196906.2158, 109043.8054, 81089.10227, 183386.8841, 
192302.1075, 77938.94147, 118711.3761, 167366.3676, 180309.8601, 
174407.0449, 99380.08521, 192730.4345, 189491.6891, 196906.2159, 
24874.86628, 102407.9819, 122178.9993, 30881.52396, 196442.9135, 
111042.0063, 196906.2159, 135534.2336, 66050.24256, 126682.0198, 
182764.5526, 114190.7689, 189491.6891, 180312.2014, 190137.6583, 
189449.8681, 187971.0012, 121449.9258, 78154.6362, 192698.9312, 
194568.6369, 74544.74404, 189449.8681, 108316.5476, 24898.16725, 
132791.5122, 28777.04168, 148918.0853, 196418.3023, 192682.0629, 
188515.4215, 126131.307, 33183.60174, 185346.9753, 159613.3784, 
196421.2717, 82004.78959, 65309.18163, 63338.00515, 180245.5915, 
62627.78768, 57720.84009, 157413.4092, 59702.44117, 87187.46136, 
189061.1605, 42292.06498, 196906.2159, 61262.26161, 102237.7457, 
180312.2015, 180298.0587, 42771.2155, 92334.99481, 182042.8242, 
140490.4741, 196664.533, 126823.1072, 195029.8994, 60074.40944, 
49109.46533, 50418.56398, 128501.5426, 167655.0629, 196444.6159, 
174407.0449, 114886.8676, 59714.23481, 60944.55308, 189449.8681, 
189449.8681, 167655.0628, 48354.20928, 130013.1393, 173375.0026, 
160083.8017, 156356.2922, 93367.9965, 155830.9163, 196434.0627, 
111036.1316, 147924.4383, 130094.4442, 110740.2619, 180250.2648, 
196459.0132, 128571.3777, 167655.0629, 160083.8017, 196877.4489, 
110073.9451, 72839.48411, 66658.72684, 34400.54341, 191366.9356, 
142614.132, 185346.9753, 195029.8994, 153000.4548, 174335.3955, 
183445.8281, 196433.8595, 195027.1862, 48164.88123, 86628.41888, 
192698.9312, 150234.408, 175199.9653, 177924.5096, 192730.4345, 
196878.3235, 187250.6512, 122178.9993, 193078.476, 122110.0691, 
180312.0705, 132791.5122, 195050.9669, 189491.6891, 196432.6449, 
110092.6632, 47544.9055, 39401.69691, 151724.8938, 174367.861, 
163267.6496, 84959.82215, 195050.9669, 174334.3813, 114385.5926, 
136121.5477, 174335.3954, 99380.08521, 96012.29654, 196903.8799, 
188981.9462, 26900.33901, 144806.3775, 181896.5244, 182719.3605, 
61102.65255, 19741.08644, 174407.0449, 196186.7084, 174407.0449, 
49160.44088, 185294.9958, 189447.4007, 195029.8994, 78249.88294, 
175443.5234, 196906.2159, 196426.4033, 188983.876, 48447.89584, 
72293.81391, 120400.3747, 75707.85928, 137471.9858, 60187.19617, 
68395.23939, 86832.80395, 180312.0461, 189797.7904, 33511.74556, 
196906.2159, 154302.1127, 132791.5122, 66767.84315, 151141.734, 
172547.7844, 196434.0627, 99380.08521, 152897.0658, 99664.00085, 
193282.3168, 196044.3122, 78806.56556, 145347.3239, 171144.0818, 
31242.41669, 160083.8016, 160083.8017, 51851.21776, 74403.31886, 
22031.14274, 147071.9195, 150545.6883, 61023.94095, 195042.1262, 
196896.4658, 40242.42874, 192254.7086, 190394.1262, 70406.2492, 
137426.2258, 99380.08519, 140062.7414, 192633.0614, 176633.5859, 
180250.2648, 53869.02935, 142613.3149, 135530.3915, 168519.8947, 
185169.7176, 174407.0449, 178691.312, 196443.0624, 148079.4063, 
57246.18123, 27932.81263, 40415.31582, 114466.1176, 179818.8947, 
93706.47211, 131532.3781, 192726.5206, 167655.0628, 74544.74404, 
79470.40371, 67332.54758, 54594.64538, 86527.34867, 151724.8937, 
142506.9822, 185109.6548, 87288.26795, 26623.47308, 62365.95905, 
40654.42647, 174837.3988, 166235.3165, 192730.4345, 146116.5008, 
159993.6391, 72847.57489, 195050.9669, 177538.7456, 196906.2159, 
149249.3871, 196397.3296, 57847.69421, 87174.39279, 159993.6391, 
111062.6658, 159993.6391, 196334.4073, 113564.9231, 50944.96715, 
92400.13042, 174069.8016, 174335.3954, 152177.3195, 177458.1197, 
99127.75301, 41868.22708, 122178.9993, 178391.3338, 180294.9067, 
173326.9519, 99041.17658, 84287.92399, 99380.08519, 167074.1011, 
192698.9312, 23275.03706, 194567.4548, 174407.0449, 110640.4665, 
38304.51098, 116760.5063, 32312.56115, 192698.9312, 194912.5765, 
30074.00305, 196434.0627, 64801.13889, 132791.5122, 172063.1196, 
172932.0266, 95204.73836, 191443.2656, 167294.3229, 167603.8976, 
168460.7176, 137621.5109, 195050.9669, 35523.49542, 87187.46136, 
176019.8707, 118457.6403, 196434.0627, 111062.6969, 142614.132, 
90241.70834, 174407.0449, 195050.9669, 185346.5708, 195050.9669, 
186066.4133, 196434.7768, 186583.1961, 185346.692, 151626.0232, 
188760.7471, 167655.0629, 196419.9902, 74544.74403, 192727.0388, 
156139.2832, 171684.6684, 55093.68422, 180312.2015, 185294.9959, 
103656.4268, 196444.6159, 174407.0449, 138519.227, 46366.84254, 
192730.4345, 180312.2015, 180312.2015, 196414.8666, 165251.9959, 
116955.1283, 132045.4789, 193991.0508, 71828.64499, 151651.5674, 
186625.3351, 143211.3547, 43983.46389, 20833.59855, 189482.4773, 
137525.1996, 189449.8681, 120134.4853, 122178.9993, 167655.0629, 
188336.9525, 89348.85526, 180033.6182)), row.names = c(NA, -500L
), class = "data.frame")

# X and Y limits
x_min <- min(data$Longitude)
x_max <- max(data$Longitude)
y_min <- min(data$Latitude)
y_max <- max(data$Latitude)

# World map
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

# CRF
crf <- CRS(projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs")

# Plot 
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = pred)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") +
  geom_sf(data = world, fill = alpha("lightgrey", 1), color = "lightgrey") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(x_min, x_max), ylim=c(y_min, y_max), crs = crf, expand = FALSE)
```

I get this warning when I run the above code:

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol) : 
invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead. 
2: Raster pixels are placed at uneven vertical intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead. 
3: In f(...) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
4: In f(...) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

I have tried using geom_tile / geom_stars and rounding my lat/lon values to no avail.

I think the issue might be arising due to the projection used which means the area of a grid cell decreases as you move away from the equator, hence I have also included grid cell  area in the data (4th column).

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Ideally without interpolating as these are already model predictions.

If you need the full dataset it can be found here: https://github.com/Rawizard/stack_overflow/blob/main/SO_question_data1.RDS

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve this would be to perform an interpolation on your data.

Here is an option based on the practical guide [found here](https://swilke-geoscience.net/post/spatial_interpolation/)

#### Code

---

Starting by rounding the longitude and latitude with 0 digit. (`unique()` is to get rid of the duplicate data only 2 rows here)

```
library(dplyr)
df = data
df = df %>% dplyr::select(c(Longitude, Latitude, prediction))
df = df %>% mutate(across(c(Latitude, Longitude), round, digit = 0)) %>% unique()
```

Then creating a grid which will be used to interpolate the data:

```
df_template = expand.grid(Longitude= seq(min(df3$Longitude), max(df3$Longitude), 1), Latitude = seq(min(df3$Latitude), max(df3$Latitude), 1))
> head(df_template)
  Longitude Latitude
1      -178      -83
2      -177      -83
3      -176      -83
4      -175      -83
5      -174      -83
6      -173      -83
```

Rasterizing the grid:

```
grd_template_raster <- df_template %>% dplyr::mutate(Z = 0) %>% raster::rasterFromXYZ(crs = crf)
```

Transformation of the data into simple feature:

```
sf_df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = crf)
```

Model fitting in this case Nearest Neighbour

```
library(gstat)
fit_NN <- gstat::gstat( # using package {gstat} 
  formula = prediction ~ 1,    # The column `NH4` is what we are interested in
  data = as(sf_df, "Spatial"), # using {sf} and converting to {sp}, which is expected
  nmax = 10, nmin = 5 # Number of neighboring observations used for the fit
)
```

Interpolate by running the model the data:

```
library(raster)
interp_NN = interpolate(grd_template_raster, fit_NN)
```

Extract the data to build the plot with ggplot:

```
df_final <- rasterToPoints(interp_NN) %>% as_tibble()
colnames(df_final) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "prediction")
```

Plotting the data:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = df_final, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = prediction)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") +
  geom_sf(data = world, fill = alpha("lightgrey", 1), color = "lightgrey") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(x_min, x_max), ylim=c(y_min, y_max), crs = crf, expand = FALSE)
```

[image: geom_raster]

Comment: Thank you for that clear and concise answer. Did you try plotting before interpolation, would this work?

Comment: geom_raster() would not work, however you can work around by calling geom_point() and increase the size to overlap the points

Comment: Ok thank you, the thing that confuses me is why geom_raster won't work, the grid cells are at the 4 degree resolution and span nearly the entirety of the worlds oceans. 

Ideally I would like a solution that plots the data as it is as I have trained a model on a subset of data then used the full data set of covariates to make global model predictions. 

Could I use a different model for interpolation such as a GLM?